# Facebook Like button sometimes appears sometimes not

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have strange issue with like buttons on my site. When I enter a page it shows up correctly, than after refresh it doesn't appears and I have javascript error

> ```
> FB.provide is not a function
> [Break on this error] FB.provide('Array',{indexOf:function(a...|c.hasOwnProperty(d))a(c[d],d,c);}});
> ```

Initialization and asynchronous including of js looks like this

```
<body>
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({appId: 'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
              };
              (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                e.async = true;
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
              }());
            </script>
```

And heres the input code of like and share buttons:

```
<fb:like href="<%= link -%>" layout="button_count" font="arial"></fb:like>

<a title="Share" name="fb_share" type="button_count" share_url="<%= link -%>" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried removing `/js/FB.Share` script (for testing)?

Comment: I too have similar problem. This errors appears only in Firefox.

Comment: Goran, placing the all.js on your own server is not recommended, as it is a 'work-in-progress'-kinda file -- they keep changing it from time to time.

Answer (score 6):

I found that order also matters, so when loading files dynamically, all.js should be loaded before FB.share js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
              };
              (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                e.async = true;
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
              }());

              $(document).ready(function(){
                var s = document.createElement('script');
                s.type = 'text/javascript';
                s.src = 'http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share';
                s.async = true;
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(s);
              });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

When I loaded the all.js file the way you did, I also had a problem, but when I downloaded all.js manually and copied it somewhere on the site. After that, loading it through the script tag made this problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

After you are done with placing your html in DOM, just call `window.fbAsyncInit();`.