# Facebook share and comment boxes don't work together

Tags: facebook

I want to include Facebook share button and comment box to my website.

I have a code for share button:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
<a name="fb_share" type="icon"  share_url="www.example.com"></a>
```

For comment box:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=258471354227171";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="www.example.com" data-num-posts="3" data-width="600"></div>
```

Separately it works perfect, but when i put it in one page just one of them is working. What is a problem?

Comment: Can you check if the firebug console fires any errors?

Comment: Yes, I get "FB.provide is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution you need is here:

[Facebook Like button sometimes appears sometimes not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309131/facebook-like-button-sometimes-appears-sometimes-not)

Basically you need to add the FB.share script after all.js.